# pip3 install needs multiple retries

Tags: python, pip

is it common that pip package installation requires multiple retries before it works?
I tried on windows and ubuntu and noticed the same issue, with and without conda.

[image: example]

Second example now on windows:

```
(textgen) C:\w\RedHeart\text-generation-webui>pip3 install accelerate==0.18.0 --verbose --no-cache

(textgen) C:\w\RedHeart\text-generation-webui>pip3 install accelerate==0.18.0 --verbose --no-cache
Using pip 23.0.1 from C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
Collecting accelerate==0.18.0
  Downloading accelerate-0.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (215 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 215.3/215.3 kB 13.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00

(textgen) C:\w\RedHeart\text-generation-webui>pip3 install accelerate==0.18.0 --verbose --no-cache
Using pip 23.0.1 from C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
Collecting accelerate==0.18.0
  Downloading accelerate-0.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (215 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 215.3/215.3 kB ? eta 0:00:00
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 419, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 373, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 213, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 204, in _get_updated_criteria
    self._add_to_criteria(criteria, requirement, parent=candidate)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 44, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 279, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 896, in find_best_candidate
    return candidate_evaluator.compute_best_candidate(candidates)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 579, in compute_best_candidate
    applicable_candidates = self.get_applicable_candidates(candidates)
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 464, in get_applicable_candidates
    versions = {
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 464, in <setcomp>
    versions = {
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 205, in filter
    if self.contains(parsed_version, **kw):
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 183, in contains
    if normalized_item.is_prerelease and not prereleases:
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 370, in is_prerelease
    return self.dev is not None or self.pre is not None
  File "C:\Users\levy\miniconda3\envs\textgen\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 342, in dev
    return self._version.dev[1] if self._version.dev else None
AttributeError: 'Version' object has no attribute '_version'

(textgen) C:\w\RedHeart\text-generation-webui>
```

Comment: This is not common - I've actually not seen this happen before at this stage. Do you have any memory limits or constraints on your user/system?

Comment: I didn't see any segmentation fault at my end when I tried to install this same package on my Python 3.10 on Windows. I suspect it could possibly be some temporary network instability issue that has caused some installation failures for you.

Comment: The computer is a i9-13900K, with 32gb ram and a Nvidia 4090, with nothing else installed other than vs studio, conda and nvidia drivers.
I just re-installed windows, to try again, and I'm still getting errors with pip, look at the second example I just added in the post, I retried 10 times or so and no success yet.
I also tried disabling firewall and windows defender.. I will try a different network just to validate if it's not it.

Comment: Just tried with my mobile network and had the same issue, even with no-cache  param.